# Calculating extent of custom tiles?

Tags: postgis, openlayers, tiles, mapnik, extents

**Problem**

The picture is just an example of my case, but I am left with blank space on the left when I load all the tiles and I get error message in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://path/to/the/tile//base/8/6/53.png 
etc.
```

[image]

I could guess and limit the extent of the layer, but I would really like to know is there any way to calculate it and also be able to get rid of the error message.

**What I know about the tiles?**

- Originally they are served as TMS
- They represent png images 256*256
- They are in projection: EPSG:3857
- In OpenLayers2 they were called like TMS layer
- In OpenLayers3 (v.3.8.2) they are called like XYZ layer (that includes `-y`):

---

```
var baseLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: 'http://path/to/the/tiles/base/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png'
  })
});
```

**Thoughts and questions**

1. How can I calculate extent of the tiles? Or in another words how can I find out **zmin zmax xmin ymin xmax ymax** or whole range of x/y?
2. What does x/y really represent? Are they coordinates of the left bottom corner or center of the tile?
3. In which direction does x/y increase?
4. How can I figure out x/y of at least one of the tile, for example left bottom one?
   [image: First tile, bottom left corner]

(I have modified the question for better understanding of the problem)

Comment: A bit hard to know without knowing where the tiles come from, what projection they are in, etc. Is this some custom wmts, xyz or some such?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for mentioning that. I have edited my question.

Comment: Do you really have a -y inside the brackets? if not, then you are dealing with regular XYZ tiles. See this page for getting the extent of the tiles: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe
 I am not an expert on this subject, and I am trying to figure out how tiles are set, but I can see that it doesnt work when I have +y, and it works when I have -y. I have also found this: Tile Map Service: an early standard supported by OpenLayers. One difference is the y axis is positive southwards in TMS, and northwards in OpenStreetMap. (reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiled_web_map)

Comment: **gdaltindex** will give you the geometries of numerous images [http://www.gdal.org/gdaltindex.html](http://www.gdal.org/gdaltindex.html). I'm not sure how you would incorporate this into the above but it could be a useful reference point for you at least

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe actually in OL2 this tiles were called like TMS, and now in OL3 I was calling them like XYZ. I just ran into your comment from other question: "I Could see is that in XYZ, Y starts at the TOP while in TMS, Y starts from the bottom." I guess thats why I had to put -y. So oiginally my tiles are TMS.

Comment: @ProudGIS thanks, I could see If I could get anything from it. Can I call URL instead of folder here? Was googling, but cant find anything about it.

Comment: TMS and XYZ are the same, except with respect to the y tile coordinate. `-y` is just a succinct way of saying "use the TMS specification when requesting tiles". You can convert between XYZ and TMS y coordinate easily: https://gist.github.com/tmcw/4954720